# Permission error when I install keras package in Program Files

Tags: python, package, keras

I need to instal keras package i have anaconda3 and python 2.7.13 and windows 10 OS
where i execut this line

```
 pip install keras
```

give me this error :

```
 (C:\Program Files\Anaconda) C:\Users\User-47>pip install keras
    Collecting keras
    Using cached Keras-2.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.14 in c:\program 
    files\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from keras)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.1 in c:\program files\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from keras)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in c:\program files\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from keras)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in c:\program files\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from keras)
Installing collected packages: keras
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Accès refusé: 'C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras'
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the exception: `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Accès refusé: 'C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras'`.  Installing files in `C:\Program Files` requires an administrator account, not a user account.  Whoever installed Anaconda on the machine either used an admin account or gave an admin password in a UserAccessControl (UAC) box.  I am slightly surprised that you did not see such a box, but I guess it depends on the Windows version and settings.

People who install Anaconda just for their user account have to put it or let it be put somewhere else.